What is this meaning of 大きい?
パートナーと仲良くやっていく秘訣ってあります?
あんまり恰好つけないでいつでも素の自分でいたことが大きいかもしれません
What is this usage of 大きい? The character asked "What is the secret to get along with your partner" and this is the answer he got. I see it as "Don't show off and always show your true self" but why is 大きいused?

大きい here means to play a big role


あんまり恰好つけないでいつでも素の自分でいた

This is the part that you've translated as "Don't show off and always show your true self".
Then we add ことが, nominalizing and making it a subject: "(The idea of) not showing off and of always showing your true self".
Then we make a claim about that idea: 大きい（です）. I.e., this idea is a big one; an important one; something that plays a big part in the 秘訣 of パートナーと仲良くやっていく.

I think this is simply 大きい as in "important/valuable/decisive." Similar to how we would say, "A big part of it is just being yourself," in English.
